# html script src="" triggering redirection with button

Tags: javascript, html, src

**i have the following login.html page for login located in design folder.**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<script src="../Script/login.js">

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h3> Login</h3>
<form name="login">
Location code  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="ddl1"><br>
  <option value="loc1" size=20>LH</option>
  <option value="loc2">AT</option>
  <option value="sel" selected>-------select------</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Enter UserName &nbsp;&nbsp;:  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="Text" name="inp1" size=20><br><br>
Enter Password &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="password" name="pwd1" size=20><br><br>

<button type="button" name="login" onclick="log()">Login</button> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**and also i have onother folder named scripts that contains the following login.js file**

```
function log()
{
 var li=parent.head.document.getElementById('lin');
 var lo=parent.head.document.getElementById('lou');
 
 var passid = document.login.pwd1.value;
 var passid_len = passid.length;
 
 var un=document.login.inp1.value;

 var e = document.getElementById("ddl1");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if(strUser=="loc1" || strUser=="loc2")
{
  if (passid_len >= 5) 
  {  

   if(un=="admin")
    { 
     parent.nav1.location.href = 'nav_admin.html';
     document.write("Hello admin");
     li.style.display = "none";
     lo.style.display = "";
    }
    else if(un=="clerec")
    {
      parent.nav1.location.href = 'nav_clerk_reception.html';
      document.write("Hello reception clerk");
      li.style.display = "none";
      lo.style.display = "";
    }
    else if(un=="cledep")
    {
     parent.nav1.location.href = 'nav_clerk_departemnt_operations.html';
     document.write("Hello dept clerk");
     li.style.display = "none";
     lo.style.display = "";
    }
    
     else if(un=="guest")
    {
     parent.nav1.location.href = 'nav_guest.html';
     document.write("Hello Guest");
     li.style.display = "none";
     lo.style.display = "";
     }
     else
    {
     document.write("Wrong user name and password");
    } 
   }
   else
    {
     document.write("password should be minimum 5 characters");
    }
   }
   else
    {
        document.write("Choose Location");
    }
 }
 
 function fnlog1()
{
 var lo=parent.head.document.getElementById('lou');
 var li=parent.head.document.getElementById('lin');
 lo.style.display = "none";
 li.style.display = "";
 parent.nav1.location.href = 'navigate.html';
 }
```

when i click `log in` button nothing works....no redirection takes place....html page does not call `log()` function....

Comment: is there any error on browser ... please do use developer tool and try to find out the error ... also check if you have given correct path of the js file

Answer (score 10):

First you are linking the file that is here:

```
<script src="../Script/login.js">
```

Which would lead the website to a file in the Folder `Script`, but then in the second paragraph you are saying that the folder name is

> and also i have onother folder named scripts that contains the the following login.js file

So, this won't work! Because you are not accessing the correct file. To do that please write the code as

```
<script src="/script/login.js"></script>
```

Try removing the `..` from the beginning of the code too.

This way, you'll reach the js file where the function would run!

**Just to make sure:**

Just to make sure that the files are attached the HTML DOM, then please open Developer Tools (F12) and in the network workspace note each request that the browser makes to the server. This way you will learn which files were loaded and which weren't, and also why they were not!

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your foldername is `scripts` ?

Change

```
<script src="../Script/login.js">
```

to

```
<script src='scripts/login.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: <script src="ThisSucks.js" type="text/javascript"></script> I get no error no matter what file name I put in. No wonder there are so many security problems. Any mis-typed filename or path turns into a back door for hackers.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem but i found out that it was a permissions problem I changed my permissions to 0744 and now it works. I don't know if this was your problem but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

your folder name is scripts..

and you are Referencing it like ../script/login.js

Also make sure that script folder is in your project directory

Thanks