# Audio bar is showing but not playing (HTML)

Tags: html, css, audio

I was able to add a audio bar to my webpage by using below html code, but the song doesn't play. Can someone help why it might be? It's a 5 min song, can it be because of that or am I doing something wrong?

```
<body>
    <audio controls> 
      <source src="./song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Just make sure the song's name is correct and is in the same folder as your .html file.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me.. make sure the mp3 file your using is in the same folder as your HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls> 
      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be because of the `type/mpeg` or try:

```
<audio controls> 
  <source src="/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

maybe because of your body tag or maybe the ../ you added in.if you put the ../ in this:

```
<script src="../yourname"></script>
```

a script src it doesnt work.

Check this link for proof:https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374331/13879249

So you just did ./ change that to /

Maybe the mp3 file is not in your folder.

or probaly copy the file location for it.So your browser knows where it should be or if you dont then the browser will just display anything called song.mp3.

maybe the mp3 is not in your directory.

also change ./song.mp3 to song.mp3.

becuase it adds /. to song.mp3 and the browser will look for anything called ./song.mp3 but the file location thing works

Thanks for your service.

#Stackoverflow

S.I.T